# How to make an Option Object be selected as the Default Value

Tags: javascript, json, dom

The following code triggers just before a page is loaded. Now I've managed to fill a select with values. But I'm not sure on how to make the first value to be the deafault selected value.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#searchpage',
//This function is the whole function that runs when the pagebefore event occurs
function () {
    //This reads the universities from the api we created
    $.getJSON(AddressAccess + "Home/university/format/json",

    function (data) {
        //The data is sent back in a collection of objects. We need to extract each object and do relative operations
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var university = data[i];
            var SelectDropDown = document.getElementById("searchuniversity");
            var NewOption = new Option(university.Name, university.UniverstiyID);

            if (i == 1) {
                SelectDropDown.add(NewOption, Selected);
            } else {
                SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
            }

        };
    });
});
```

Now if i use `SelectDropDown.add(NewOption,Selected);` Only one option is made as an option in the select and what I want is to just make the first option being read from my json data to be the default option appearing in the select.

Comment: Please format your code so that is easier to read for others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `selectedIndex` of `SelectDropDown` to 1:

```
if (i == 1) {
  SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
  SelectDropDown.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

If you're really talking about the *very first* option from the options list, `selectedIndex` should be 0. The `options` array of a `select` element is zero based.

[**edit**] based on your comment:
maybe the `select` already contains a blank option. Try:

```
if (i < 1) {
  SelectDropDown.options.length = 0;
  SelectDropDown.add(NewOption);
  SelectDropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: When I use your code and I load the page the select appears still blank but when I click the select, the drop down menu appears and in that drop down the 1st item is selected. But select doesn't reflect what was selected in the drop down dialog. Maybe this is a bug in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I'm quite sure that setting `options.length` will throw an error instead of removing the nodes. Edit: OK, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionsCollection) and the latest HTML standard implement a special `HTMLOptionsCollection` where this is allowed (in contrast to the usual `HTMLCollection`), but I wouldn't trust this

Comment: The SelectedIndex definitely works the reason it doesn't show in the select box is because of jquery mobile. I've got to change the following property: $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = false; but I'm honestly not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [`defaultSelected` property of the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) to true:

```
var newOption = new Option(university.Name, university.UniverstiyID);
newOption.defaultSelected = true;
```

Or use the parameters of the [`Option` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Option):

```
var newOption = new Option(university.Name, university.UniverstiyID, true, true);
```